# Can't set Carbon date to null in Laravel 5

Tags: php, datetime, model, laravel-5.1

I have a column `dateTime` in my migrations that Laravel assumes as `Carbon`. The column name is `terminado_em` and is nullable.

I have setted a `Carbon` value using my model.

Now when I want to set `terminado_em` to `null`:

```
public function reiniciar()
{
    $this->terminado_em = null;
    ...
}
```

I get the error

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Data missing
```

How to set a `Carbon` property to null when it's already set to a `Carbon` value?

Answer (score 1):

I could not set the object Carbon property directly accessing the property `$this->terminado_em`, but accessing the generic model `attributes` property it worked.

```
$this->attributes['terminado_em'] = null;
```